# GeoServer WMS tiling

Tags: geoserver, tiles

In GeoServer(my version is 2.21.1), locate to the "Layer Preview" page, and click "OpenLayers" link, in the popup window, there is a **Tiling** attribute [image], I'm confused about this because, in my understanding, the "Tile" term is in the WMTS context.

I opened F12 in Chrome, choose **Tiling** to 'Tiled', and seen even it is set to 'Tiled', the background network is also WMS

[image].

Can someone explain what the 'Tiled' means here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to make tiled-alike requests from WMS if the client just knows the bbox of the tile. The size of tile to be used in GetMap is fixed usually to 256x256. OpenLayers knows how to generate such requests. The advantage is that tiles can be cached on the client side.

The OpenLayers documentation about Tiled WMS is at https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-tiled.html.

> WMS can be used as a Tile layer, as shown here, or as an Image layer,
> as shown in the Single Image WMS example example. Tiles can be cached,
> so the browser will not re-fetch data for areas that were viewed
> already. But there may be problems with repeated labels for WMS
> servers that are not aware of tiles, in which case single image WMS
> will produce better cartography.